# Google Safebrowsing API returns empty

Tags: python, json, google-api, python-requests

I'm trying to check multiple URLs on Google Safebrowsing API, but it returns an empty response every time. Have been googling for quite few hours with no results, and I don't need some overkill library for a simple POST request.

Edit: Using Python 3.5.2

```
import requests
import json

api_key = '123456'
url = "https://safebrowsing.googleapis.com/v4/threatMatches:find"
payload = {'client': {'clientId': "mycompany", 'clientVersion': "0.1"},
           'threatInfo': {'threatTypes': ["SOCIAL_ENGINEERING", "MALWARE"],
                          'platformTypes': ["ANY_PLATFORM"],
                          'threatEntryTypes': ["URL"],
                          'threatEntries': [{'url': "http://www.thetesturl.com"}]}}
params = {'key': api_key}
r = requests.post(url, params=params, json=payload)
# Print response
print(r)
print(r.json())
```

This is my code, that returns HTTP 200 OK, but the response is empty.
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the `Safe Browsing API` [documentation](https://developers.google.com/safe-browsing/v4/lookup-api), if you receive an empty object is because there was no match found:

> **Note**: If there are no matches (that is, if none of the URLs specified
>   in the request are found on any of the lists specified in a request),
>   the HTTP POST response simply returns an empty object in the response
>   body.

Answer (score 2):

I have the feeling that the api is not working properly. It returns 200 empty result even for urls that are marked as dangerous. For example, I checked this [url](https://testsafebrowsing.appspot.com) using [google's form](https://transparencyreport.google.com/safe-browsing/search) and got the result `Some pages on this site are unsafe``. But using the api, it returns 200 empty...  I believe it returns results only for specific pages. If only some pages are **infected/dangerous**, then you won't get any data for the main domain... Not very useful if you're asking me, but hey...it's free.
It would be nice if someone from Google could confirm this and add it to the documentation.
A real malware test url would have been much appreciated also, so we can test with real data.